# EntityManager has stopped running update statements after upgrading to wildfly 18

Tags: java, jpa, wildfly, java-11, wildfly-18

I've just updated from wildfly 12 to 18, and from Java 8 to 11. No code has been changed within my project. Running the integration tests has produced a really odd problem though. UPDATE statements no longer seem to be running. For example:

```
@Transactional
public void updateStatus(final long id, final Status status)
{
    final Item item = entityManager.find(Item.class, id, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    item.setStatus(status);
    entityManager.merge(item);
}
```

Previously this would cause an update statement to be run, now nothing happens. If I call `entityManager.flush()` after the `merge()` an update statement is run, but the database does not reflect the updated entity.

No idea what might cause this sort of thing. Only thing I can think of is that some default config in wildfly 18 is different to 12?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems very similar (or the same) to this one: [How to fix hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion issue with JTA transactions in JBOSS EAP 7.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687918/how-to-fix-hibernate-transaction-flush-before-completion-issue-with-jta-transact)

Removing

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
```

From my `persistence.xml` did the trick.